# Particle Data Group book

Tags: particle-physics, soft-question

Many PDG data books have 'July' marked on their covers, does this mean they are published (and made available on their website) in July? 
When is it expected to be available this year? (date or month will be helpful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the last email of the particle data group :

> The 2016 edition will be published in summer. PDG Books containing
>   Summary Tables and review articles as well as Booklets will be mailed in
>   fall. Starting this year, the Data Listings will only be published online.

Comment: What months come under fall?

Comment: The standard northern hemisphere seasons define fall to start on the equinox of around september 23 and end on the solstice, around december 21.

Comment: So, I can access 2016 version only after September?

Comment: The online version should be out during summer. Fall corresponds to the mailing of the paper versions.

Comment: Which months do you mean by summer, please?

Comment: june july august are the summer months